# Converting one XML document into another XML document

Tags: c#, xml, linq, .net-3.5

I want to convert an XML document containing many elements within a node (around 150) into another XML document with a slightly different schema but mostly with the same element names. Now do I have to manually map each element/node between the 2 documents. For that I will have to hardcode 150 lines of mapping and element names. Something like this:

```
XElement newOrder = new XElement("Order");
newOrder.Add(new XElement("OrderId", (string)oldOrder.Element("OrderId")),
newOrder.Add(new XElement("OrderName", (string)oldOrder.Element("OrderName")),
...............
...............
...............and so on
```

The newOrder document may contain additional nodes which will be set to null if nothing is found for them in the oldOrder. So do I have any other choice than to hardcode 150 element names like orderId, orderName and so on... Or is there some better more maintainable way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use an [XSLT transform](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp) instead. You can use the built-in .NET [XslCompiledTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx) to do the transformation. Saves you from having to type out stacks of code. If you don't already know XSL/XSLT, then learning it is something that'll bank you CV :)

Good luck!

Comment: We use xmlspy and there's a built-in editor in visual studio. I strongly recomend http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/ and http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_languages.asp.

Comment: Michael Kay's *XSLT Programmer's Guide* (Wrox Press) is indispensable.

Comment: I confirm: XSLT does good to a CV. And it’s mighty handy too.

Answer (score 1):

Use an XSLT transformation to translate your old xml document into the new format.

Answer (score 1):

XElement.Add has an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345077.aspx) that takes object[].

```
List<string> elementNames = GetElementNames();

newOrder.Add(
  elementNames
    .Select(name => GetElement(name, oldOrder))
    .Where(element => element != null)
    .ToArray()
  );
```

//

```
public XElement GetElement(string name, XElement source)
{
  XElement result = null;
  XElement original = source.Elements(name).FirstOrDefault();
  if (original != null)
  {
    result = new XElement(name, (string)original)
  }
  return result;
}
```